# AdoNetAppender and Clob field

Tags: log4net, adonetappender

I have a asp.net 3.5 app that is using log4Net and AdoNetAppender.  Currently the app uses a message field just like the log4net documentation http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html.  I would like to convert the field from varchar2 to Clob.  I was trying to find some documentation on how to do this.  All I could find is:

http://old.nabble.com/DbType-for-CLOB-column-using-AdoNetAppender-td1214036.html#a1214036

which wasn't too useful.  Does anyone know a link or some samples on how to use a Clob file with a AdoNetAppender?

Thanks, Bill N

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

http://marc.info/?l=log4net-user&m=110874200319166

basically you need to set the `DbType` to `string` and remove the `Size` parameter. Apparently this does not work correctly for nvarchar(max) (see [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-202)) but that does not mean it will not work for Clob.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I recently needed to pass a CLOB parameter to a package procedure, using log4net. I was not able to do that using the suggestions I found online, including the one with setting the DbType to String and removing Size.

I am using an Oracle package procedure that takes a parameter of type CLOB. Using a custom AdoNetAppenderParameter I am able to pass long strings (270k+ characters) to the procedure and store them in the DB (Oracle 9i).

First of all, I had to use Oracle's Data Access Provider (after all, Microsoft's System.Data.OracleClient has been [deprecated](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/15/system-data-oracleclient-update.aspx)). Your project must reference Oracle.DataAccess.dll. I got the NuGet package by searching for "oracle.dataaccess" in NuGet package manager.

The library has an implementation of DbParameter, **OracleParameter**, that has a OracleDbType property. The type of the property is [OracleDbType](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/OracleDbTypeEnumerationType.htm) which is an enumeration that has the **Clob** value.

After adding the reference, I changed the appender's connection type to:

```
<connectionType value="Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection, Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
```

I then created a custom AdoNetAppenderParameter that creates a new OracleParameter and sets its type to Clob:

```cs
public class OracleAdoNetAppenderParameter : AdoNetAppenderParameter
{
    public OracleDbType OracleDbType { get; set; }

    public override void Prepare(System.Data.IDbCommand command)
    {
        if (!(command is OracleCommand))
        {
            string message = string.Format("The log4net parameter of type {0} can only be used with an appender connection of type {1}. The expected command type, {2}, cannot be supplied. Please check the parent appender's connectionType property.",
                                             this.GetType(), typeof(OracleConnection), typeof(OracleCommand));

            throw new System.ArgumentException(message, "command");
        }

        var parameter = command.CreateParameter() as OracleParameter;

        parameter.ParameterName = base.ParameterName;
        parameter.OracleDbType = this.OracleDbType;

        command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
    }
}
```

I exposed a property, OracleDbType, so I would be able to specify it through configuration.

I initially did not expose the property, named the class OracleClobAdoNetAppenderParameter and set the OracleDbType property to Clob inside the Prepare method.

After I created the class, I added the parameter to the appender's configuration, like this:

```
<parameter type="YourNamespace.OracleAdoNetAppenderParameter, YourAssembly">
    <OracleDbType value="Clob" />
    <parameterName value=":yourProcedureClobParam"/>
    <layout type="..."></layout>
 </parameter>
```

You can use your own layout. I am passing my large string through log4net's context as a custom parameter.

Here's the final configuration I'm using:

```
<appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
      <connectionType value="Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection, Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
      <connectionString value="data source=xxx;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx"/>
      <commandText value="MY_PKG.LogMessage"/>
      <commandType value="StoredProcedure" />
      <!-- SERVICE_MESSAGE -->
      <parameter type="MyNamespace.OracleAdoNetAppenderParameter, MyAssembly">
        <OracleDbType value="Clob" />
        <parameterName value=":service_message"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawPropertyLayout">
          <key value="service_message"/>
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <!-- LOG_LEVEL -->
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value=":type"/>
        <dbType value="String"/>
        <size value="20"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%level"/>
      </parameter>
      <!-- LOG_DATE -->
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value=":timestamp"/>
        <dbType value="DateTime"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
      </parameter>
      <!-- MESSAGE -->
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value=":message"/>
        <dbType value="String"/>
        <size value="1000"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%message"/>
      </parameter>
      <!-- EXCEPTION -->
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value=":error"/>
        <dbType value="String"/>
        <size value="4000"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout"/>
      </parameter>
......
</appender>
```

Hope it helps.